# mean of a column in pandas dataframe when the 'count' value is total

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 4 |
| yes | 3 |
| yes | 3 |
| total | nan |
| yes | 5 |
| yes | 5 |
| total | nan |

Desired output when the value of count column is total then replace the nan with mean of above values that is 4+3+3/3 ,, 5+5/2

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 4 |
| yes | 3 |
| yes | 3 |
| total | 3.33 |
| yes | 5 |
| yes | 5 |
| total | 5.0 |

Comment: First get the indices of all the rows that has 'total' for column 'A', and then calculate mean  in between two indices. If you can, please provide the dataframe in reproducible way

Comment: Please also show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's load the data

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""
A   B
yes 4
yes 3
yes 3
total   nan
yes 5
yes 5
total   nan
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
df['B'] = df['B'].astype('float')
```

First we calculate the mean by group -- groups are defined as being separated by NaN

```
dfm = df.groupby((df['B'].shift().isna()).cumsum(), as_index = False).mean()
dfm
```

we get

```
    B
0   3.333333
1   5.000000
```

now we can asign these to the right cells in df:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'total','B'] = dfm['B'].values
df
```

for the end result

```
    A   B
0   yes     4.000000
1   yes     3.000000
2   yes     3.000000
3   total   3.333333
4   yes     5.000000
5   yes     5.000000
6   total   5.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation